# To get the details of action performed on HTML element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have a page with lot of HTML elements and want a script that captures the action and on which element it was performed.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('*').bind('click dblclick mousedown mouseenter mouseleave',
                detectEvent);

    function detectEvent(e) {
        alert(e.type);
    }
  });
  </script>
```

But even this script doesn't provide the requirement.

Comment: I'd recommend using Firebug or Chrome/IEs' native Developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). It will give you all the events currently attached on the page with loads of information about them